# How to get usbhub serial number / metadata using Java in Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, serial-port, osx-lion

So what i'm trying to do is get the serial number for a usb to serial converter. I have an FTDI FT232 usb to serial computer connected to a Mac OSX and i would like to read the metadata for that usb to serial interface.

In Mac OSX the FTDI FT232 usb to serial converter shows up under USB subsection in System Information. 
Is there a way to read this metadata information that is presented here, using Java.

Under windows similar information is presented in the device manager and can be accessed through the windows registry. I am wondering if there is a way similar to that for accessing this metadata.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the USB hierarchy using a command line tool. I described the process [in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26137431/748976).